# Objective-C Late Static Binding

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, dynamic-binding, late-static-binding

I'm teaching myself Objective-C as a guilty pleasure, if you would. I have a self-proclaimed strong grasp of the Java language, so it's not a *terribly difficult* transition – it sure is fun though. But alas, my question!

I'm attempting to reproduce something that exists in PHP:  Late Static Binding. In PHP, I can decorate a method call with "static::", which will dynamically bind that method to the caller at runtime. On the other hand, if the keyword "self::" is used, the binding is static and is associated with the class in which it resides, regardless of which child class calls it.

In Obj-C, I'm having difficulty reproducing this paradigm. I've asked my overlord, Google, how to late statically bind in Cocoa, but I don't think it's possible. It may be called something else, or it may require a very over-my-head workaround. Here's what I'm doing now:

Parent Class Method:

```
-(id) whoAmI {
 return ([self class]);
}
```

A child class, ChildClass, extends ParentClass and does not override instance method whoAmI.

```
NSLog(@"Calling from PARENT: %@", [parent whoAmI]);
NSLog(@"Calling from CHILD: %@", [child whoAmI]);
```

When I send the message to each of the class objects, dynamic binding does what it's supposed to do, and I get the following from NSLog():

**2010-09-21 11:39:07.484 WhoAmI[4803:a0f] Calling from PARENT: Parent

2010-09-21 11:39:07.486 WhoAmI[4803:a0f] Calling from CHILD: Child**

Ultimately, I want to learn – if possible – how to get Cocoa to stop dynamically binding so that the whoAmI method always returns the object in which it resides (always Parent). I also want it to be an instance method. How would I go about doing this?

-Sean

Comment: I'm not sure if this will get you what you're looking for, but changing your `whoAmI` method to `return [Parent class];` will result in always returning the object in which that method resides.

Comment: This is precisely what I'm looking for! I did not know of the Parent keyword. Thank you so much kubi. Could you post this as an answer, so that I may tag it as the accepted answer?

Comment: Sean, I think you misunderstood kubi's comment. There is no Parent keyword, I think he was referring to your 'ParentClass' class. A more general way to achieve what kubi is saying is to use [superclass class].

Comment: Echelon, I see what you mean. I knew I'd get in trouble for naming those classes like such. Thank you for the clarification. That, along with kubi's answer, helped me accomplish my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Objective C has a powerful set of introspection features, and it is almost certainly possible to do what you want by referring to Apple's extensive [Objective C Runtime documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html). This is a complete C API for accessing the inner workings of Objective C's object & class hierarchy.

If nothing else, by experimenting with this stuff you'll learn a lot about how the language works and it should help you in debugging difficult problems.

Comment: This Runtime Documentation from Apple offers me the EXACT control I'm looking for. Once again, thank you Echelon.

Answer (score 0):

Change the method to incorporate the name of the Parent class (or the superclass):

```
-(id) whoAmI {
 return ([Parent class]);    //In this instance, Parent is the superclass
}
```

It just so happens that what I wished to create had to be brought about by statically binding my class message to the parent class itself:  Parent.